# Alignment Issues Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been facing rather a lot of difficulty here.. basically I am using dreamweaver to test out a site I will be designing however I am running into some unexpected difficulty when trying to align elements - the problems seemed to start one I had linked up font awesome. I am also linked into bootstrap.

Here is my code, basically you can see the three column elements under the main image. These should be aligned centre as you can see by my code...but they are not. When I use the text-align it does centre briefly...then goes back to normal. It seems a little buggy and I CANNOT see why this is happening.

Can anyone offer advice or see where the error of my ways are?

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
background-color: #EFEFEF;
margin: 0;
height:2000px;
}
nav, article, section, footer, header, summary {
    display:block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #2C2C2C;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
background-color:#C0393B;
color:white;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.navbar {
margin-bottom:0px;
border: 0px solid;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
text-align:center;
width:auto;
    }
.dropdown-menu {
min-width:80px;
}
#home {
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;
width:100%;
min-height: 100vh;
height:100vh;
background:url("images/slide-bg.jpg") fixed center 0px#444;
z-index:1;
}
.home-content {
.home-content {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index: 3;
}
.services h2, p {
text-align:center;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Alex Wiley</title>
<!--Bootstrap Code-->
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js ">        </script>

<!--End Bootstrap-->
<style type="text/css">
@import url("stylesheet.css");
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav id="navigation">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
            <div class="pull-left"><img src="http://www.thewebcreator.co.uk/hammer.png" style="height:50px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Team  <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                <li><a role="menuitem" href="#Test">Web</a></li>
                <li><a role="menuitem" href="#Test2">Print</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

<section id="home">
<div class="home-content text-center">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 home-inner">
         <h1 style="color:white">Alex Wiley</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="icons-s">
     <div class="services col-md-4">
     <h2>Stunning Design</h2>
     <p>We aim to provide and coherent, brspoke design perfect for you.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="services col-md-4">
     <h2>Premium Hosting</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="services col-md-4">
     <h2>Intricate Coding</h2>
     <p>Cutting edge code to provide your audience with the best possible eperience</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

</body>
```

Anybody got any ideas because I have actually been stick on this for hours...

Comment: you can't test on regular browser like chrome? that's what most ppl will use to view your website, not in dreamweaver.

Comment: everything's fine in all browsers

Comment: I have been testing this in Chrome & Dreamweaver. It is 100% not working for me!